# Check if service is running not behaving right

Tags: android

I created a boolean to check if a service is running, if it is running I want it to show  linearlayoutA and if it is not running I want it to show another linearlayoutB.

The problem is this, it shows the right linear layout when I start the activity, if the service is running it shows linearlayoutA if its not running it shows linearlayoutB but when I start the service in the activity it shows linearlayoutB and does not change to A even when the service as stopped until I close the application and open it. method for checking

```
public boolean isRunning(Class<? extends Service> serviceClass) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(TimerActivity.this, serviceClass);
        return (PendingIntent.getService(TimerActivity.this, CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    }
```

This is how I call it in onCreate of the activity

```
if(isRunning(TimerLocationService.class)){
            setWaitScreen(true);
        }else{
            setWaitScreen(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
private Boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceName) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceName.equals(runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: have tried this before, doesn't do anything except if there is something additional am meant to do

Comment: do you try `isServiceRunning(TimerLocationService.class.getClassName())`?

Comment: no i didn't and it shows cannot resolve for getClassName()

Comment: its like the service doesnt get destroyed till i close the application, is there any other way to exit a service

Comment: do you want to kill your service, or to check your service's running?

Comment: to check if its running